# How to rewrite theme path using .htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm hoping you guys can help me out. I want to rename my theme's CSS & JS path but I can't seem to figure it out. 
For example:

I want to change:

`http://cdn.(domain-name).com/wp-content/themes/smart-mag/style.css`

to

`http://cdn.(domain-name).com/style.css`

& from:

`http://cdn.(domain-name).com/wp-content/themes/smart-mag/js/bunyad-theme.js`

to

`http://cdn.(domain-name).com/js/bunyad-theme.js`

etc, etc.

Here is what I tried in my .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^wp-content/themes/smart-mag/screenshot\.png|readme\.html|license\.txt|wp-content/debug\.log|wp-includes/$ /nothing_404_404 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(css|js|jpe?g|gif|png|bmp)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/themes/smart-mag/
RewriteRule ^(.*) /themes/smart-mag/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
#END WordPress
```

That modified htaccess did nothing at all. What am I missing/doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the order of your rules. The wordpress rules route *all requests* to index.php, including your `/style.css` etc URLs. So you need to route those first.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(css|js|jpe?g|gif|png|bmp)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/themes/smart-mag/
RewriteRule ^(.*) /themes/smart-mag/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^wp-content/themes/smart-mag/screenshot\.png|readme\.html|license\.txt|wp-content/debug\.log|wp-includes/$ /nothing_404_404 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php
</IfModule>
#END WordPress
```

Comment: That still didn't change anything.